# Testing validation of bean with lots of properties (and child objects)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, javabeans

Using Springboot 2.5.7 with bundled Junit5 (via spring-boot-starter-test), I'm trying to test the constraints that I have put in place all over the bean via custom an standard annotations.

Most of the documentation I found was about junit4 and I cannot find a way to make it work in springboot's junit5.

Also, I'm a bit puzzled because, ideally, I would like to test contraint per constraint and only found documentation on how to test it globally (using junit4).

Does anyone already fiddled with that kind of testing?

Just for the sample, here I have a bean for my inbound SQS event:

```
package com.application.sqs.dto.inbound;

import com.application.sqs.dto.validators.ZoneDateTime;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class SqsEvent {

    private String version;

    private String id;

    private String source;

    private String account;

    @ZoneDateTime(
            message = "Wrong time."
    )
    private String time;

    private String region;

    private List<String> resources;

    private SqsPayload detail;
}
```

And an example of a payload (that has lots of child objects, edited):

```
package com.application.sqs.dto.inbound;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.application.sqs.dto.validators.LocalDate;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SqsPayload {
    @JsonProperty("primkey")
    @NotBlank(
            message = "primkey is blank"
    )
    private String primarykey;
    
    @JsonProperty("numb")
    @Pattern(
            regexp="^(A|B)$",
            message = "numb is invalid"
    )
    private String number;

}
```

I'd like to test that numb only accepts A or B, that primkey must not be blank and that my custom validator (@ZonedDateTime) is working as intended for example.

Thanks a lot for your help and guidance!

Best,

Comment: Haven't done per individual constraint, only on entire classes. If you run an instance of that class through the javax validator, then you will get one ConstraintViolation per invalid constraint. That way, you could just validate that you get all expected ConstaintViolation's for each constraint.

Comment: Another way could be to have define a valid mock object, and then in each test case, you just change a value of a constrained field into an invalid case, and ensure that it catches it.

Comment: Having a valid mock object, only modifying the stuff that I want to test is what I envisioned also. That being said, I can't find ressource on how to use the javax validator and get ConstraintViolation in return in springboot + junit5, do you have any doc link?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done per individual constraint, but below are 2 possibilities.

### Option 1

If you run an instance of that class through the javax validator, then you will get one ConstraintViolation per invalid constraint. That way, you could just validate that you get all expected ConstaintViolation's for each constraint.

### Option 2

define a valid mock object, and then in each test case, you just change a value of a constrained field into an invalid case, and ensure that it catches it

### Details on programmatic javax validation

For programmatic javax validation, you could [have a look here](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) on step 5.

Also suggest you have a deeper look at the `javax.validation.Validator` interface on available methods. You also have a method called validateProperty to target specific properties as well.